# How to disable android back button across every screen?

Tags: java, android

Do we need to override `onBackPressed()` method for every screen? I do not see any other ways to do so. Please let me know if there is a more simpler way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

make a super class for all of your activities e.g.

```
class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    void onBackPressed() {  }

}
```

and then make all of your activities inherit from this class

```
class MyActivity1 extends BaseActivity { ... }

class MyActivity2 extends BaseActivity { ... }

class MyActivity3 extends BaseActivity { ... }
```

And all of your activities now wouldn't react to any back press event!

Answer (score 0):

Create a BaseActivity and override onBackPressed() method with required logic
And extend BaseActivity in all Activity

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        //super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

extend this BaseActivity instead of AppCompatActivity

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {
    //Your code
}
```

If you want to handle back button manually for some Activity then just override it for those Activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `FragmentActivity` or `AppCompatActivity` you can do this with [OnBackPressedDispatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedDispatcher) that controls dispatching system back presses.

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {

            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(@NonNull Activity activity,
                                          @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                if (activity instanceof FragmentActivity) {
                    ((FragmentActivity) activity).getOnBackPressedDispatcher()
                            .addCallback(new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
                                @Override
                                public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                                    // nothing to do
                                }
                            });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityStarted(@NonNull Activity activity) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityResumed(@NonNull Activity activity) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityPaused(@NonNull Activity activity) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityStopped(@NonNull Activity activity) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(@NonNull Activity activity,
                                                    @NonNull Bundle outState) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityDestroyed(@NonNull Activity activity) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application 
    android:name=".App"
    ...
    />
```